# C# british summer time (BST) timezone abbreviation

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I need to display a label with the current time zone abbreviation.  My pc's timezone is currently set to "(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London".  As a result, I would like to see BST displayed, since LN is currently in british summer time.

It looks like that info (timezone abbrev) is not available.  Looking at the GMT TimeZoneInfo, all I can see with regard to names is

```
Id  "GMT Standard Time"
StandardName    "GMT Standard Time"
DaylightName    "GMT Daylight Time"
```

Is there any way to get to BST from "GMT Daylight Time" or any other available Windows timezone info?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `TimeZoneInfo` class referrers to "British Summer Time" as "GMT Daylight Time", so no it is not possible. If Microsoft were to store it as "BST" it would be in the `DaylightName` property.

Whilst following the development of the `TimeZoneInfo` class on the BCL blog many years ago, I saw no explanation behind how they chose the values for `DaylightName`. If I were to guess it would be because this is for a "Time Zone" and not a particular city.

It appears that the public-domain [tzdatabase](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ZEFRAM/Time-OlsonTZ-Data-0.201203/tzsrc/tz-link.htm), which is considered to be more complete than Microsoft's time zone database, does display BST for London ([source](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/xtra/tzdate?tz=Europe/London)). This is because Cities are included in this dataset, not just the Time Zones.
There is a Project called [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) that brings the tzdatabase to .Net that is now avaialble.

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to Noda Time Beta nuGet packages.

Answer (score 6):

You should know that all the time zones that say "Standard" will properly switch to daylight time in the summer. For example `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time")` will be an object that can properly handle both standard and daylight times. The same is true for, say, `"Pacific Standard Time"`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two choices:  Special case handling for the GMT time zone, or generalized handling for "Time zones for which Microsoft uses an incorrect name."

I wonder, for example, whether the Portuguese use "GMT" for their time zone in the winter.  Whether they do or not, I doubt they use "British Summer Time" in the summer!