# British Summer Time (BST) not handled by .Net

Tags: .net, datetime

I am currently consuming an RSS feed in .Net (luckily still testing).

I noticed that the feed was throwing an invalid datetime error.

It appears that .Net doesn't handle BST times as this is not a valid timezone in windows.

Take the following dates

Mon, 05 Oct 2009 08:00:06 GMT

Tue, 01 Apr 2014 17:00:00 BST

THe second string is not a valid datetime if you try to parse it using something like this

```
if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dt))
    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, CustomUtcDateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Is this really the case?

I know I can write something to remove the timezone but really?

Comment: Well what's `CustomUtcDateTimeFormat`? We don't have enough information at the moment to reproduce the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# british summer time (BST) timezone abbreviation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126252/c-sharp-british-summer-time-bst-timezone-abbreviation)

Comment: British Standard Time or Bangladesh Standard Time?  CST is a dozy, it can mean 3 different zones.  How do you expect .NET to tell the difference?  It doesn't.

Comment: Jon, quite simple to reproduce the problem, you'd think with all your points you'd be able to work that out? Hans, you and your comment are a waste of time. Maurice, thanks for your answer. It is a duplication I would say so you are correct. Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's .NET framework considers BST the same as GMT Daylight Time.

There is a more complete date and time management framework available for .NET, [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/).

Noda Time uses the TZ Database for its time zones, which includes BST.

Comment: thanks for the info. I'll probably just reformat the input string tho... cheers